# Search box layout problem

Tags: forms, gui-design, layout, search

I have two similar kind of searches:

- Clients: can be searched by code, name, state (active or inactive) and zone.
- Companies: can be searched by code, name and zone.

Client zone and companies zone have different kind of information (for example, clients zone should be a country and companies zone a region).
Both searches results have the same data structure so, they can be showed in the same data grid.

I have designed this layout with tabs, but it doesn't convince me. Code and name are shared in two forms but zone combo have different items. It would be nice to find some way to join them in a unique form.

[image]

Comment: I take it they search over different tables?

Comment: yes, clients and companies are stored in different database tables

Comment: so you do need two different searches.

I've come across this situation frequently and the key is the user must be aware of the two scopes; be aware of how to choose between the two scopes.

Comment: Well, clients and companies are not the real names. I have choose them to make problem description easy. Actually, searches are over "clients that work for my company at present" and "future clients". I haven't found the exact words in english. Searches are over the same scope (clients) but both types have different information.

Comment: "clients that work for my company at present" = current clients. You can [edit] tje question to add that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to have only one search form with Code, Name and Zone. Additionally, first option would be a radio button/switch for Client or Company. Depending on what user selects, Zone will populated with respective items. To add more context, near Zone, mention what it contains like for Clients - Countries, and Companies - regions.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you have "Zone" for both if it's actually a different field?
I'd rather call it what it is. (when having two distinct forms)

Using a different background for the tabs could also help to distinguish then.

Combining the "Zone" dropdown to have one form would be weird i guess (having items of different types in one dropdown)

Comment: I use zone in both because I use a unique grid result with same title headers. Country and Region are mapped to Zone in a grid, so I use this word in the search box too.

Comment: but why not have the actual header (country/region) in there as well.
i think it's confusing if the table header is a "generic" term that combines different meanings

Comment: I agree, header column could change.

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents, How about combining them on one tab and the user can freely select which information they want to display. Is it a client or company, since they have almost the same fields.

After applying, your information on the table view will display accordingly based on what the user selected.